# Typing a function dynamically using a subset of a ParamSpec

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing, typing

I have a decorator that should be used to test certain things prior to the function that it decorates is being called, and if the checks fail just raise an exception. The decorator itself takes callables as input, and these callables will accepts a subset of the parameters from the function that it decorates.

For example, if I have a function that takes in `name` and `age`, the decorator could accept a function that takes a single parameter `age` and checks that its over 18. The problem I am having is with typing this properly, since my inputs to my decorator should be callables that take a subset of the parameters or the function that the decorator is attached to.

I tried with this:

```
import functools
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import ParamSpec, TypeVar

P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")


def decorator_with_input(
    *inputs: Callable[P, bool],
) -> Callable[[Callable[P, R]], Callable[P, R]]:
    
    def decorator(func: Callable[P, R]) -> Callable[P, R]:
        @functools.wraps(wrapped=func)
        def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
            for input_ in inputs:
                if not input_(*args, **kwargs):
                    raise ValueError

            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return decorator


def func1(a: int, *_, **__) -> bool:
    return bool(a)


def func2(b: str, *_, **__) -> bool:
    return bool(b)


@decorator_with_input(func1, func2)
def func3(a: int, b: str) -> tuple[int, str]:
    return a, b


func3(a=1, b="b")
```

Which gives me a bunch of errors from mypy:

t.py:34: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "Callable[[int, str], Tuple[int, str]]"; expected "Callable[[VarArg(), KwArg()], Tuple[int, str]]"  [arg-type]

t.py:34: error: Argument 1 to "decorator_with_input" has incompatible type "Callable[[int, VarArg(Any), KwArg(Any)], bool]"; expected "Callable[[VarArg(), KwArg()], bool]"  [arg-type]

t.py:34: error: Argument 2 to "decorator_with_input" has incompatible type "Callable[[str, VarArg(Any), KwArg(Any)], bool]"; expected "Callable[[VarArg(), KwArg()], bool]"  [arg-type]

t.py:39: error: Argument "a" to "func3" has incompatible type "int"; expected   [arg-type]

t.py:39: error: Argument "b" to "func3" has incompatible type "str"; expected   [arg-type]

My question essentially comes down to, how can I type this? It feels like I should make `*inputs` be a callable but instead of `P` having a subset of `P` - but what from I can tell I cant make another `ParamSpec` which is bounds to `P` since mypy then says:

error: Only the first argument to ParamSpec has defined semantics  [misc]

Comment: I don't think there is any way to capture the *separate* types of each function in a type-level list. Your current attempt asserts that every function in `args` has the *same* type.

Comment: hmm yeah I know its slightly off currently - but not sure how to fix it

Comment: I don't think you *can*. `P` only applies to a single `Callable`, not a list of `Callable`s. You need some sort of type-level list support (which doesn't currently exist) that could capture the signatures of *different* functions. Perhaps you could pre-compose the individual predicates into a single function with the same argument type as `func3` and pass *that* to `decorator_with_input`?

Comment: hmm due to the use case where this will be implemented it doesnt really work

Comment: Please note that your overall function is ill-defined: it requires using kw-only parameters when there's more than one parameter. In your example, if it was `func1` returning `bool(a)` and `func2` returning `not b`, call `func3(1, 0)` would be unexpectedly rejected (both checkers will operate on `1`). You really need this contract enforced somehow (probably with `inspect` or at least `mypy` using `Protocol`), and I'd even prefer lower type safety to have `def wrapper(**kwargs)` denying positional args in the actual call.

Comment: ah yeah you're right - will have to update the functions as well